# Motivation and examples of parabolic manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

Let $(M^{n},g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, we say that $M$ is *parabolic* if the constant functions over $M$ are the only subharmonic functions which are bounded above, i.e, for a function $u \in C^{2}(M)$, if we have $\Delta u \geq 0$ and $u\leq u^{*}<\infty$, then $u$ is constant. Liouville's theorem for subharmonic functions asserts that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a parabolic manifold.

I would like to know two things about this definition:

1. What is the motivation for the study of parabolic manifolds?
2. If $N$ is a complete Riemannian manifold, then $\mathbb{R}^{2} \times N$ is parabolic. Why?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can look at Peter Li's book.

> ..., the existence and nonexistence of a positive Green’s function divides the class of complete manifolds into two categories. In general, the methods in dealing with function theory on these manifolds are different, hence it is important to understand the difference between the two categories.

--Peter Li, **Geometric Analysis**, chapter 20.

For the second question, in Axler, Harmonic Function Theorey,there's an exercise

> (a) Show that a subharmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is bounded above must be constant.
>
> (b) Suppose $n > 2$. Find a nonconstant subharmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is bounded above.

From which we know that $\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^{n-2} ~ (n\geq 3)$ is not parabolic.